# Can a vptr be subject to data races?

Tags: c++, inheritance, undefined-behavior, race-condition

If `ipc` calls the lambda on a separate thread then is there a data race in this code? If the vtable is not fully constructed yet then the lambda may call `Base::Handle()` but if it is then it will call `Derived::Handle()`, right?

```cpp
#include <thread>
#include <chrono>
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>
#include <mutex>
#include <condition_variable>

struct IPC {
    IPC() : t([&]{
        std::unique_lock lk(mut);
        cv.wait(lk, [&]{ return (bool)f; });
        f();
    }) {}

    void SetHandler(std::function<void()> f_) {
        {
            std::unique_lock lk(mut);
            f = f_;
        }
        cv.notify_all();
    }

    std::mutex mut;
    std::condition_variable cv;
    std::function<void()> f;
    std::thread t;
};

struct Base {
    Base() {
        ipc.SetHandler([this]{ Handle(); });

        // Maybe construction of Base takes some time.
        // Removing this sleep makes the output of the program stabilize on "Derived".
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::microseconds(10));
    }
    virtual void Handle() { std::cout << "Base" << std::endl; }
    IPC ipc;
};

struct Derived : Base {
    void Handle() override { std::cout << "Derived" << std::endl; }
};

int main()
{
    Derived b;
    // I only care about interaction with constructors so join here
    // to delay destruction of b until the test is finished.
    b.ipc.t.join();
}
```

Running this code multiple times in succession on my laptop produces randomly alternating outputs of "Base" and "Derived".

```
developer@WDX591VWD3:~$ g++-10 -std=c++20 hi.cpp -lpthread
developer@WDX591VWD3:~$ ./a.out
Base
developer@WDX591VWD3:~$ ./a.out
Derived
developer@WDX591VWD3:~$ ./a.out
Base
developer@WDX591VWD3:~$ ./a.out
Base
developer@WDX591VWD3:~$ ./a.out
Base
developer@WDX591VWD3:~$ ./a.out
Base
developer@WDX591VWD3:~$ ./a.out
Base
developer@WDX591VWD3:~$ ./a.out
Base
developer@WDX591VWD3:~$ ./a.out
Base
developer@WDX591VWD3:~$ ./a.out
Base
developer@WDX591VWD3:~$ ./a.out
Base
developer@WDX591VWD3:~$ ./a.out
Base
developer@WDX591VWD3:~$ ./a.out
Base
developer@WDX591VWD3:~$ ./a.out
Base
developer@WDX591VWD3:~$ ./a.out
Base
developer@WDX591VWD3:~$ ./a.out
Base
developer@WDX591VWD3:~$ ./a.out
Base
developer@WDX591VWD3:~$ ./a.out
Base
developer@WDX591VWD3:~$ ./a.out
Base
developer@WDX591VWD3:~$ ./a.out
Base
developer@WDX591VWD3:~$ ./a.out
Base
developer@WDX591VWD3:~$ ./a.out
Base
developer@WDX591VWD3:~$ ./a.out
Base
developer@WDX591VWD3:~$ ./a.out
Base
developer@WDX591VWD3:~$ ./a.out
Base
developer@WDX591VWD3:~$ ./a.out
Derived
developer@WDX591VWD3:~$ ./a.out
Base
developer@WDX591VWD3:~$ ./a.out
Base
developer@WDX591VWD3:~$ ./a.out
Base
developer@WDX591VWD3:~$ ./a.out
Base
developer@WDX591VWD3:~$ ./a.out
Base
developer@WDX591VWD3:~$ ./a.out
Derived
developer@WDX591VWD3:~$ ./a.out
Base
developer@WDX591VWD3:~$ ./a.out
Base
developer@WDX591VWD3:~$ ./a.out
Base
developer@WDX591VWD3:~$ ./a.out
Base
developer@WDX591VWD3:~$ ./a.out
Derived
developer@WDX591VWD3:~$
```

So I guess the question is: Is this undefined behavior? How long do I need to wait before IPC would be able to call the handler such that the derived class handler is called? Do I need to do any synchronization?

Comment: Next time, post a [mcve], like [this one](https://godbolt.org/z/qfsfdMxdo).  You can add to that code something that has to do with the concerns of thread-safety and repost that example here.

Comment: This is just how c++ deals with the situation of calling a virtual function from the constructor. The derived object has not been constructed yet, so the virtual call just calls the `Base` implementation. There is no data-race.

Comment: The ipc callback may be called on a separate thread. If it is, then it's behavior depends on when that call happens, or it seems to depend on when the call happens based on my minimal reproducible example I have created. Seems like a data race to me.

Comment: No threads in the example code.  Data races across threads needs to be handled by the programmer.

Comment: @xdaimon If the ipc thread calls `Handler()` before both `Base` and `Derived` constructors have finished running, then yes, it is a race condition. But if the ipc thread does not call `Handler()` until after the `Derived` constructor is finished, then there is no race condition.

Comment: @Eljay I know there is no threads in the **provided** example code. I am lazy. SORRY! I will whip something up later tonight.

Comment: The vtables (in a vtable/vptr implementation) aren't "constructed" - they're constant data. The vptr in the Base subobject is guaranteed to point at the Base vtable during the `Base()` constructor body, and to point at the Derived (or Base-in-Derived) vtable during the `Derived()` constructor body. The compiler-generated modification of that vptr in between could essentially be a "data race".

Comment: I think the C++ Standard doesn't technically consider this a "data race", but it does make it UB. The [rules](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/class.cdtor#4) which make some things valid in a constructor or destructor, or in a function called directly or indirectly from the constructor or destructor, can't apply to a different thread.

Comment: It's  not a data race.  It might be considered a race condition.  Either way, it's unsafe to access an object before all the constructors have finished.  This all just boils down to an asynchronous call to a virtual member function from inside the base constructor.

Answer (score 1):

That's going to have undefined behavior.

While I think that the standard currently lacks some wording to that effect, it is in my opinion intended that the object may be used in another thread only after the construction of the most-derived object has finished.

A similar provision is given in [[class.cdtor]/2](https://eel.is/c++draft/class.cdtor#2) when trying to access the object through a pointer that is not derived from `this`.

I also expect that it isn't intended to matter whether or not the class is polymorphic. The restriction linked above also doesn't apply only to polymorphic classes.